# How to pass jvm arg to java app distribution created with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build

Gradle provides a handy `application` plugin which you can use like this

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "foo.bar.Baz"
```

then invoke "*dist" tasks and get some scripts generated to run the app

```
bin/
  app
  app.bat
lib/
  ...
```

however when i run `sh app -DmyConfig=myValue` the application won't get a jvm argument by name myConfig.

**So how do we pass arguments trough command line?**

Comment: What do you mean by "jvm arguement"? The -D parameter should be set as system property like usual with -D and normal parameters land in parameter of main method as usual.

Comment: Yes i mean system property, which is accessed trough System.getProperty(), but this way it wont work...

Comment: I want to pass a system property like when you call java -jar ... but when i do the same with gradle shell script application does not see that parameter...

Comment: Ah, you are right, I remembered wrongly, one moment I'll write an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All parameters you give the default launch script generated by Gradle are passed on like they are to the main method of your program, but there are some environment variables you can set, or you can do the setting in your main method.

So either you parse your args in `main` and set the system properties from your code, or you set environment variables. The default Gradle-generated launcher scripts consider three environment variables that it adds together. `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS` which is set within the launcher script, `JAVA_OPTS` which is meant for all Java programs that respect this property and one additional environment property that is specific to your program. Just look inside the launcher script to find out its name.

As third option you can of course also use an own launcher script that does special handling of parameters that start with -D and sets them as system properties instead of giving them to your programs `main` method.

---

As your question suggests that you are working in a linux shell, one way to set an environment variable just for one call of an app would be `YOUR_APP_OPTS="-DyourProp=yourVal" ./yourApp`. But any way to set an environment variable would be fine.